# Issue using code from JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Does anyone know why my code works correctly on JSFiddle but not when I use the code on my website?

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3d928/3/)

On my website I have included the following link in my header:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your JFiddle loads the scripts on page load. How are you initializing your page. What happens when you change the way JavaScript is loaded in your JFiddle? (on load, document ready, etc.)

Comment: What is the problem in your code?

Comment: You're attaching 2 click events for the same item, choose beween `onclick` in your HTML or `on('click')`

Comment: @hutchbat the 2 click events are to 1) set the cookie and 2) hide the DIV. If I remove the onclick in the HTML, how do I then call the function?

Comment: @helderdarocha only OnLoad seems to work in JSFiddle. I don't think I'm initialising my page. How do I do this?

Comment: Show us what your code looks like...

Comment: @Dominik the code I'm using is in the JSFiddle

Comment: Well if that was the case it would work wouldn't it?! ;)

Comment: @Dominik could you explain why?

Comment: @user3220812 You can use only `on.('click')`

Comment: Because there is obviously a difference here otherwise both implementations would work the same... So it all depends on the difference which we can't see right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @helderdarocha, your jsFiddle is set to run onLoad. This means that jsFiddle automatically wraps all the JS code in a window.ready() event.

There are a couple of options in JSFiddle

- onLoad
- onDomReady
- No wrap (in head)
- No wrap (in body)

Depending on which option you choose, JSFiddle generates your code in different ways.

For example, using **onLoad** generates the following source code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    function TermsAndConditions() {
        days = 30;
        myDate = new Date();
        myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        document.cookie = 'TermsAndConditions=Accepted; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();
    }

    var cookie = document.cookie.split(';')
    .map(function(x) {
        return x.trim().split('=');
    })
    .filter(function(x) {
        return x[0] === 'TermsAndConditions';
    })
    .pop();

    if (cookie && cookie[1] === 'Accepted') {
        $("#terms-and-conditions").hide();
    }

    $('.accept-button a').on('click', function() {
        TermsAndConditions(); // set cookie
        $("#terms-and-conditions").hide(); // hide element
        return false;
    });
});
```